# airflow TriggerDagRunOperator how to change the execution date

Tags: triggers, airflow

I noticed that for scheduled task the execution date is set in the past according to

> Airflow was developed as a solution for ETL needs. In the ETL world,
>   you typically summarize data. So, if I want to summarize data for
>   2016-02-19, I would do it at 2016-02-20 midnight GMT, which would be
>   right after all data for 2016-02-19 becomes available.

however, when a dag triggers another dag the execution time is set to now().

Is there a way to have the triggered dags with the same execution time of triggering dag? Of course, I can rewrite the template and use yesterday_ds, however, this is a tricky solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following class expands on `TriggerDagRunOperator` to allow passing the execution date as a string that then gets converted back into a datetime. It's  a bit hacky but it is the only way I found to get the job done.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import logging

from airflow import settings
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.models import DagBag
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator, DagRunOrder

class MMTTriggerDagRunOperator(TriggerDagRunOperator):
    """
    MMT-patched for passing explicit execution date
    (otherwise it's hard to hook the datetime.now() date).
    Use when you want to explicity set the execution date on the target DAG
    from the controller DAG.

    Adapted from Paul Elliot's solution on airflow-dev mailing list archives:
    http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-dev/201711.mbox/%3cCAJuWvXgLfipPmMhkbf63puPGfi_ezj8vHYWoSHpBXysXhF_oZQ@mail.gmail.com%3e

    Parameters
    ------------------
    execution_date: str
        the custom execution date (jinja'd)

    Usage Example:
    -------------------
    my_dag_trigger_operator = MMTTriggerDagRunOperator(
        execution_date="{{execution_date}}"
        task_id='my_dag_trigger_operator',
        trigger_dag_id='my_target_dag_id',
        python_callable=lambda: random.getrandbits(1),
        params={},
        dag=my_controller_dag
    )
    """
    template_fields = ('execution_date',)

    def __init__(
        self, trigger_dag_id, python_callable, execution_date,
        *args, **kwargs
        ):
        self.execution_date = execution_date
        super(MMTTriggerDagRunOperator, self).__init__(
            trigger_dag_id=trigger_dag_id, python_callable=python_callable,
           *args, **kwargs
       )

    def execute(self, context):
        run_id_dt = datetime.strptime(self.execution_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        dro = DagRunOrder(run_id='trig__' + run_id_dt.isoformat())
        dro = self.python_callable(context, dro)
        if dro:
            session = settings.Session()
            dbag = DagBag(settings.DAGS_FOLDER)
            trigger_dag = dbag.get_dag(self.trigger_dag_id)
            dr = trigger_dag.create_dagrun(
                run_id=dro.run_id,
                state=State.RUNNING,
                execution_date=self.execution_date,
                conf=dro.payload,
                external_trigger=True)
            logging.info("Creating DagRun {}".format(dr))
            session.add(dr)
            session.commit()
            session.close()
        else:
            logging.info("Criteria not met, moving on")
```

There is an issue you may run into when using this and not setting `execution_date=now()`: your operator will throw a mysql error if you try to start a dag with an identical `execution_date` twice. This is because the `execution_date` and `dag_id` are used to create the row index and rows with identical indexes cannot be inserted.

I can't think of a reason you would ever want to run two identical dags with the same `execution_date` in production anyway, but it is something I ran into while testing and you should not be alarmed by it. Simply clear the old job or use a different datetime.

Comment: It is a good solution, far away from being the best one, it still helps ( a lot ).

Comment: current (v1.9.0) airflow has the index on (dag_id, run_id)... is your comment regarding the sql error for an earlier airflow version?

Comment: I am running v1.8.0, so you may be right that it is a non-issue in 1.9+

Comment: I am running airflow 1.9.0 and I have the same error. `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dag_run_dag_id_execution_date_key`

`Key (dag_id, execution_date) already exists.`

Answer (score 6):

The `TriggerDagRunOperator` now has an `execution_date` parameter to set the execution date of the triggered run.
Unfortunately the parameter is not in the template fields.
If it will be added to template fields (or if you override the operator and change the template_fields value) it will be possible to use it like this:

```
my_trigger_task= TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id='my_trigger_task',
                                              trigger_dag_id="triggered_dag_id",
                                              python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
                                              execution_date= '{{execution_date}}',
                                              dag=dag)
```

It has not been released yet but you can see the sources here:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py

The commit that did the change was:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/089c996fbd9ecb0014dbefedff232e8699ce6283#diff-41f9029188bd5e500dec9804fed26fb4

Answer (score 3):

I improved a bit the MMTTriggerDagRunOperator. The function checks if the dag_run already exists, if found, restart the dag using the clear function of airflow. This allows us to create a dependency between dags because the possibility to have the execution date moved to the triggered dag opens a whole universe of amazing possibilities. I wonder why this is not the default behavior in airflow.

```
   def execute(self, context):
        run_id_dt = datetime.strptime(self.execution_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        dro = DagRunOrder(run_id='trig__' + run_id_dt.isoformat())
        dro = self.python_callable(context, dro)
        if dro:
            session = settings.Session()
            dbag = DagBag(settings.DAGS_FOLDER)
            trigger_dag = dbag.get_dag(self.trigger_dag_id)

            if not trigger_dag.get_dagrun( self.execution_date ):
                dr = trigger_dag.create_dagrun(
                       run_id=dro.run_id,
                       state=State.RUNNING,
                       execution_date=self.execution_date,
                       conf=dro.payload,
                       external_trigger=True
                )
                logging.info("Creating DagRun {}".format(dr))
                session.add(dr)
                session.commit()
            else:
                trigger_dag.clear( 
                    start_date = self.execution_date,
                    end_date = self.execution_date,
                    only_failed = False,
                    only_running = False,
                    confirm_prompt = False, 
                    reset_dag_runs = True, 
                    include_subdags= False,
                    dry_run = False 
                )
                logging.info("Cleared DagRun {}".format(trigger_dag))

            session.close()
        else:
            logging.info("Criteria not met, moving on")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function available in the experimental API section of airflow that allows you to trigger a dag with a specific execution date. 
 https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py

You can call this function as a part of **PythonOperator** and achieve the objective.

So it will look like
`from airflow.api.common.experimental.trigger_dag import trigger_dag`

```
trigger_operator=PythonOperator(task_id='YOUR_TASK_ID',
                                python_callable=trigger_dag,
                                op_args=['dag_id'],
                                op_kwargs={'execution_date': datetime.now()})
```