# Airflow set run_id with a parameter from the configuration JSON

Tags: airflow

I wish to automatically set the run_id to a more meaningful name.

As I understood, right now the run_id is set in the TriggerDagRunOperator.
I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808520/airflow-triggerdagrunoperator-how-to-change-the-execution-date) thread a suggestion for replacing the TriggerDagRunOperator for the data.

I also wish that the change will apply when using the Airflow UI.

1. Is it possible to pass the run_id from the config?
2. If I do change the operator,  how do I permanently make the UI to use this operator?